# Select2 multiple breaking CSS

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I'm using the select2 found from here : https://select2.github.io/

Using it without multiple works fine, using it with multiple instantly making the element twice the height and when I search and only type 2 letters, the first letter is hidden in the left and the second is only partially visible. When I type more than 4 letters it "slides to the right" and the word is fully visible.

I'm sure this is caused by the native css of the wp theme installed a I'm using the same thing on a fresh admin template where it works fine.

How can I make it so it only spans 1 line?

Comment: I can't see any question here. How can we help?

Comment: Without any code, it is not really possible for anyone to understand your issue. One can only guess what the issue would be.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can tell you that the "two character" issue is how Select2 calculates the search width (you can reproduce it by only searching "m" repeated), but it shouldn't happen with only two characters. The rest of your question can't be answered without a MCVE.